# Excel Type Filter popup for Jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I need to have a filter ( like in Excel spread Sheet) to embedded to the 'jquery' dialog popup. in this case i need to show all the unique values in the column and check box just before that value to select to the user. when user pressed filter button i need to filter only the values that user requested through the check boxes.

Can any one please let me any approach that i must follow. 
Thanks in advance for your help and valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to develop basic grid with excel kind of filter feature. any one who will come across this type of requirement can use this answer as a foundation.

I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213162/add-button-to-jqgrid-column-header) answer from 'Oleg' to embed the filter popup screen to the basic 'jqgrid'.

in the jqgrid page declare this array with the attributes (columns) that needs to display the filter screen popup.

```
var applyFilterColumnNames = ['Id','Type','custId','UserId'];
```

and the column model should be as follows -

```
 colModel :[ 
          {name:'Id', index:'Id',hidden: true,sortable: true},
          {name:'custId', index:'custId', width:140,align:"left",sortable: true,search : false},
          {name:'Type', index:'Type', width:120,align:"left",sortable: true,search : false},
          {name:'UserId', index:'UserId', width:150,align:"left",sortable: true,search : false},
         ],
```

used that reference answer to embed the filter button function.

```
    gr.closest("div.ui-jqgrid-view").find("div.ui-jqgrid-hdiv table.ui-jqgrid-htable tr.ui-jqgrid-labels > th.ui-th-column > div.ui-jqgrid-sortable")

.each(function () {
    var idPrefix = "jqgh_" + gr[0].id + "_";

    var idIndex = (this.id).substr(idPrefix.length,this.id.length) ;

    if(includeInArray(applyFilterColumnNames,idIndex)){

        jq('<button id=btn_'+idIndex+'>').css({float: "right", height: "17px"}).appendTo(this).button({

                icons: {

                    primary: "ui-icon-gear"

                },

                text: false

            }).click(function (e) {

                var idPrefix = "jqgh_" + gr[0].id + "_";

                // thId will be like "jqgh_list_name"
                var thId = jq(e.target).closest('div.ui-jqgrid-sortable')[0].id ;



                if (thId.substr(0, idPrefix.length) === idPrefix) {

                    var colName = thId.substr(idPrefix.length);
                    //alert('Clicked the button in the column "' + colName + '"');
                    constructFilter(colName);

                    return false;

                }



            });
        //}
    }
});
```

Below is the script i used to filter the jqgrid according to the filters

```
    //Variables that use in filtering operation
    var originalData = null;
    var filteredData;
    var selectedFilters = new Object();
    var chkBoxElement;
    var firstSortColumn;


    function constructFilter(columnName){

        // for the first initiation of the filter populate current grid data to an array
        if(originalData == null || originalData == 'null'){
            try{
                // this array will hold the initail data set of the grid
                originalData  = gr.jqGrid('getGridParam','data');
                // set the first sorting grid column
                firstSortColumn = columnName;
                // check if column is associated with a formatter. if so format the originalData values accordingly.
                formatGridData(columnName);
            }catch(e){}
        }


        var colData = new Array();

        var filterDataSet;

        // if current column is equal to initial sorted column set all posible values to the check boxes in the 
        // filter screen to select. ( since this is the master sorting column and other columns will filter according to that)
        if(columnName == firstSortColumn){
            filterDataSet = originalData;
        }else{
            // set current grid data set to show as checkboxes in the filter page
            filterDataSet = gr.jqGrid('getCol',columnName,false);
        }

            for(key in filterDataSet){
                // check box element object that will hold the checkbox label and its state ( true / false)
                chkBoxElement = new Object();
                chkBoxElement.id = getValueFromArray(filterDataSet[key],columnName);

                if(typeof(chkBoxElement.id)== 'undefined'){
                    break;
                }
                // if this id is saved in previous filtering event checked option will set to true.
                 if(typeof(selectedFilters[columnName]) != 'undefined'){

                    if (includeInArray(selectedFilters[columnName],chkBoxElement.id)){
                        chkBoxElement.selected = true;
                     }else{
                         chkBoxElement.selected = false;
                     }
                } 

                colData.push(chkBoxElement);

            }

        // removing duplicates  
        var uniqueValues = removeDuplicates(colData);

        // sort the array without duplicate with the custom comparator
        uniqueValues.sort(sortComparator);

        // open the filter screen. return type will captured in the 'seletedElements' variable as pipe separated string
        seletedElements = window.showModalDialog(filterUrl,uniqueValues,"dialogWidth:400px;dialogHeight:250px;center:yes;resizable:no;status:no;help:no;");


        if(seletedElements != null && seletedElements != 'null'){
            // get selected values to the array
            selectedFilters[columnName] = seletedElements.split("|");
        }else{
            //user just close the popup (using close button) will return without doing anything
            return;
        }


        if(columnName == firstSortColumn){
            // refine filter with the non filtered data set
            refillGrid(seletedElements,columnName,originalData);
        }else{
            // send current data set to refine
            var currentDataSet  = gr.jqGrid('getGridParam','data');
            refillGrid(seletedElements,columnName,currentDataSet);
        }

    }


    function formatGridData(columnName){

        var isFormatter = gr.jqGrid("getColProp",columnName);

        if(typeof isFormatter.formatter !== 'undefined') {
                if(jq.isFunction( isFormatter.formatter ) ) {

                    for(key in originalData){

                        var plainValue = originalData[key][columnName];
                        var formattedVal = isFormatter.formatter.call(null,plainValue,null,null,null);
                        originalData[key][columnName] = formattedVal;
                    }
                } 
        }
    }


    function resetFilters(){
        for(key in applyFilterColumnNames){

             jq("#btn_"+applyFilterColumnNames[key]).button("option", { 
                    //icons: { primary: this.checked ? 'ui-icon-check' : 'ui-icon-closethick' }
                    icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-gear'}

                });
        }

        gr.jqGrid("setCaption",gridCaption);
        refreshGrid(originalData);
        originalData = null;
        firstSortColumn = null;
        selectedFilters = new Object();
    }


    function refillGrid(seletedElements,columnName,filterDataSet){
        var filteredData= new Array();
        var elementsArray;
        try{
            elementsArray = seletedElements.split("|"); 
        }catch(e){
            // this exception happens when user simply open the filter screen 
            // do nothing and close it.
            trace('Error in filter splitting -'+e);
            return;
        }

        // When user de-select all check boxes from the popup screen
        if(elementsArray == ""){
            refreshGrid(originalData);
            return;
        }
        // refine the grid data according to the filters
        var mydata = filterDataSet;

            for(i=0;i<elementsArray.length;i++){
                 var filterElement = elementsArray[i]; 

                    for(j = 0;j<mydata.length;j++){
                        if(filterElement==getValueFromArray(mydata[j],columnName)){
                            filteredData.push(mydata[j]);
                        }
                    }
            }

            // change the button icon to indicate that the column is filtered
            changeButtonIcon(columnName);
            // update the column header to indicate sort by column
            changeGridCaption(columnName);
            // fill the grid according to the passed array
            refreshGrid(filteredData);

    }

    function changeGridCaption(columnName){
        // get columns name array
        var columnNames = gr.jqGrid('getGridParam','colNames');
        // get column model array
        var colModel = gr.jqGrid('getGridParam','colModel');
        var colModelIndex=null;

        if (firstSortColumn == columnName){
            for(key in colModel){
                try{
                    if (colModel[key].name == firstSortColumn){
                        colModelIndex = key;
                        break;
                    }   
                }catch(e){}
            }

        if(colModelIndex != null){
            var columnName = columnNames[colModelIndex];
            gr.jqGrid("setCaption",gridCaption + " - Filtered based on : "+columnName);
        }   


        }
    }

    function changeButtonIcon(columnName){
         //change the button Icon
    jq("#btn_"+columnName).button("option", { 
            //icons: { primary: this.checked ? 'ui-icon-check' : 'ui-icon-closethick' }
        icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-link'}

        });
    }


    function getValueFromArray(obj,columnName){
        if(obj !=null && typeof(obj)!='undefined'){
            // if obj param is string just return it
            if(typeof obj =='string'){
                return obj;
            }else{
                return obj[columnName];

            }
        }
    }

    function sortComparator(a,b){
        try{
            var aId = a.id.toLowerCase();
            var bId = b.id.toLowerCase();
            if (aId < bId) {return 1}
            if (aId > bId) {return -1}
        }catch(e){
            return 0;   
        }
    }

    function includeInArray(arr,obj) {
        //alert(arr);
    return (arr.indexOf(obj) != -1);
    }


    function refreshGrid(results) {
    gr.jqGrid('clearGridData')
     .jqGrid('setGridParam', { data: results })
     .trigger('reloadGrid');
    }

    function removeDuplicates(valueArray){
        var arr = {};
        for ( i=0; i < valueArray.length; i++ ){
            if(valueArray[i].id != null){
                arr[valueArray[i].id] = valueArray[i];
            }

        }

        valueArray = new Array();
        for ( key in arr ){
            valueArray.push(arr[key]);
        }



return valueArray;
}
```

If something wrong here please let me know.this solution is working fine. but i really appreciate the comments in therms of performance and code best practices.

Comment: what is **jq** over here ?

Comment: jq is for $ in jquery.