# Add button to jqgrid column header

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Is there a way to add a button just next to column header? lets say just after the 'Sort indicators' ?

for a example

### | Id (button) | Name (button) |

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I suppose that you knows that you can include HTML markup in the column headers. One should just place HTML fragment instead of the text in the `colNames`. I suppose that you want to add *in all* column headers some button with an icon and do some custom actions if the button are clicked.

You can implement the requirement in many ways. In [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ButtonsInTheColumnHeaders.htm) I show just one from many possible implementation:

[image]

on clicking on the custom button an alert will be displayed which shows the name of the column which header was clicked.

The corresponding code is

```
var $grid = $("#list");
//... here the grid will be created
$grid.closest("div.ui-jqgrid-view").find("div.ui-jqgrid-hdiv table.ui-jqgrid-htable tr.ui-jqgrid-labels > th.ui-th-column > div.ui-jqgrid-sortable")
    .each(function () {
        $('<button>').css({float: "right", height: "17px"}).appendTo(this).button({
            icons: { primary: "ui-icon-gear" },
            text: false
        }).click(function (e) {
            var idPrefix = "jqgh_" + $grid[0].id + "_",
                thId = $(e.target).closest('div.ui-jqgrid-sortable')[0].id;
            // thId will be like "jqgh_list_name"
            if (thId.substr(0, idPrefix.length) === idPrefix) {
                alert('Clicked the button in the column "' + thId.substr(idPrefix.length) + '"');
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Oleg. this is what exactly i was looking for.Your Demo is really helpful. Appreciate your effort.

Comment: @Oleg How to include the icon in just one column..?

Comment: @Xavier: you should change selector in `.find` so that it returns only the column which you need.

Comment: Wish there were a more simple way to do this, but using this technique did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I have used jquery to add a button to the header.  Where my column name was "id":

```
$('#gs_id').after('<button id="clear_filters" class="button blue">Reset</button>');
```

Comment: :Thank you for answering my question. i think the above answer and the demo would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

.append may be helpful. Add a class to the column and then append button to that with requisite css.

Comment: :Thank you for answering my question. i think the above answer and the demo would be helpful.