# Multi Checkbox columns in Jqgrid

Tags: c#, jquery, jqgrid, checkbox

I have jqgrid with 4 columns each with checkboxes format, I need to get All the checkboxes values selected and unselected values based on Column Names.Is it possible?

Updated : Grid Image[image: Grid Looks Like this]

Comment: which user interface you want to have for it: button in the column header, context menu in he cells of the corresponding columns ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ButtonsInTheColumnHeaders.htm) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8215019/315935) shows how to add custom button in the column header of jqGrid. In the `click` event handler you can enumerate all rows of the grid and set the column contain to `true` or `'1'` depend on the way how you defined the column. In the way you can implement your requirements.

Comment: Oleg, I have gone through the link and attached onclick event to mybutton, What I get is  $grid[0].p.dataas blank? any reasons ..mybutton here isnt attacehd to grid header it is outside jqgrid.

Comment: `$grid[0].p.data` exists only in case of local data. You can get the data of the column with respect of `getCol` with `true` as the value of the `returntype`. In the way you will receive the array like ` [{id:1,value:true},{id:2,value:false}` and can set the rows with `false` value to `true` using `setCell` for example.

Comment: Forgot, to tick :) ...$("#table").jqGrid('getCol', 'add') gets the value.Thank you somuch.