# Is it possible to have column header filtering in jqGrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I've taken a look over all of the examples over at [jqGrid Demos](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) but have been unable to find an example of column header filtering.

Take for example how Excel works:

[image: Example of filters]

Is it possible to enable this type of sorting, which gives a distinct list of fields in a drop down menu?

I've noticed that [this particular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875294/two-related-questions-on-jqgrid-column-header-filters-and-the-advanced-filtering) displays them, but ideally I'd like to do it by default without having to open and set filters in the filter window.

Sorry I don't have any code to show, I'm look more for a general yes/no and pointer if so, maybe with a couple of quick examples thrown in.

So, am I in luck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every software product have its *own user interface*. You should not expect that one can simulate GUI of Microsoft Excel in another product like in jqGrid for example. If you click on the column header of the grid (I mean jqGrid) for example then the grid will be sorted by the clicked column. Try to make Excel to do the same instead of selection of the column. It's also not easy.

In general everything is possible. I posted in [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8215019/315935) with an example of implementation of buttons in the column header. [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5329014/315935) shows how to construct selects or jQuery UI Autocomplete in the filter toolbar dynamically based on all different values in the column. [One more answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12875703/315935) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10851429/315935) shows how to use jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget written by Eric Hynds.

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19427444/315935) (and [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19404013/315935)) contains [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/usageformetterselect2.htm) which demonstrates the usage of [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) plugin. The plugin provides functionality which is very close to Excel. Probably it can be mostly close to what you need.

I hope that usage of ideas from the referenced answers you can implement your requirements.

Comment: Excellent, thank you Dr Kiriljuk, the functionality of the linked demo is sufficient for what I need.